# Pass a free function to invoke?

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, overloading, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
void f(int) {std::cout << "void f(int)" << std::endl;}
void f(double) {std::cout << "void f(double)" << std::endl;}
void f(int*) {std::cout << "void f(int*)" << std::endl;}
std::invoke(f, 3);
```

I have two questions:

- With free functions (not functors), is it possible to pass the whole overload set of `f` and let `invoke` select the right one? (without any helper class, it's a pure language question)
- If it's not possible then how to pass `void f(int)` to `invoke`? (what are all the possible syntax then, if there are several)

Comment: For the second question - yes you need to use `static_cast<>` to select proper overload - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874478/use-stdbind-with-overloaded-functions

Comment: @Vincent  Try std::invoke<void( int )>(f, 3);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do it is to manually create the overload set.

```
#define OVERLOADS_OF(name) [&](auto&&... args) -> decltype(name(FWD(args)...)) noexcept(noexcept(name(FWD(args)...))) { return name(FWD(args)...); }
```

And then pass this in:

```
invoke(OVERLOADS_OF(f), 3)
```

This way, the compiler is still doing overload resolution for us - we don't have to do this ourselves - and the overload taking the `int` is called as desired/expected.

Note that this isn't exactly equivalent to passing the intended function directly (notable exceptions include functions taking objects of nonmovable types by value), but it's the best you can do without explicit, manual type selection.

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler parses

```
std::invoke(f, 3);
```

it does not look at the implementation of `invoke` to figure out which overload of `f` is the best fit.

Hence, `f` cannot be resolved by the compiler without additional info. You can provide the additional info by casting `f` to the appropriate overload.

```
std::invoke(static_cast<void(*)(int)>(f), 3);
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `static_cast<void(*)(int)>(f)` and `static_cast<void(&)(int)>(f)`?

Comment: @Vincent, for this use case, either should work. I don't see any significant difference between the two.

Answer (score -1):

You can just specify the first template argument explicitly.

```
std::invoke<void( int )>(f, 3);
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void f(int) {std::cout << "void f(int)" << std::endl;}
void f(double) {std::cout << "void f(double)" << std::endl;}
void f(int*) {std::cout << "void f(int*)" << std::endl;}

int main() 
{
    std::invoke<void( int )>(f, 3);
    std::invoke<void( double )>(f, 3);
    std::invoke<void( int * )>(f, nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
void f(int)
void f(double)
void f(int*)
```

Another approach is to use an intermediate pointer. For example

```
void ( *pf )( int ) = f;
std::invoke( pf, 3 );
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Every template argument of [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) is intended to be derived from the function arguments and used in perfect forwarding. Specifying the template parameter breaks this. STL's talk [*Don't Help the Compiler*](https://youtu.be/AKtHxKJRwp4) mentions this.

Comment: @Justin I am sorry but I have not understood what specifying the first template argument breaks.

Comment: @Justin And moreover in my opinion the code is more clean and readable than using static cast for the first argument..